# Enolate ion opening an epoxide?

Tags: organic-chemistry, nucleophilic-substitution, enolate-chemistry

Does anyone know if it is possible to open an epoxide and do a 2-C extension using an enolate ion, say, of acetone? Here's an example of what I mean:

[image]

Based on what I know of enolate chemistry, this shouldn't be problematic, but I've never seen it.

I have done some preliminary literature searching and checked out masterorganicchemistry.com, etc. but have not been able to find anything about this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Never say never! :-) Here is the answer for your question (Ref.1):

> **Abstract:** We report here that (1) enolate anions of five- to seven-membered cycloalkanones nucleophilically open cyclopentene and cyclohexene oxides in 57−76% yields and with 4−8:1 diastereoselectivity; (2) enolate anions formed regiospecifically via kinetic deprotonation of 2-cyclohexenone and 2-cycloheptenone open cyclohexene oxide in 60−62% yields and with 32−95:1 diastereoselectivity; and (3) an aryl methyl ketone enolate anion opens a monosubstituted epoxide as the key step in a short synthesis of the $\gamma$-hydroxyketone (GHK) aglycon of the natural product curculigine.

**Graphical Abstract:**

[image: Epoxide Opening by Enolates]

The product(s) and selectivity are depicted in following scheme:

[image: Epoxide Opening]

**Reference:**

1. G. H. Posner, J. P. Maxwell†, M. Kahraman, "Mild, Fast, and Stereoselective Epoxide Opening by Ketone Enolate Anions. Application to Synthesis of the Norlignan Curculigine," *J. Org. Chem.* **2003**, *68(8)*, 3049–3054 (DOI: 10.1021/jo020744q).

Comment: That's somewhat interesting that the O-alkylation *decreases* when the counterion is changed from Li -> Na -> K; I would have expected it the other way around (Li should associate tightly with the negatively charged oxygen).